# how to open item in search listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, search

Hi I have a search list in which I want to click on any item. By clicking a particular position, item on that position should open. I have done the following :

```
public List<DBSearch> searchByName(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from  biography  where name like '%" + name + "%'", null);
        List<DBSearch> dbsearch = new ArrayList<>();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){

            DBSearch sea = new DBSearch();
            sea.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
            sea.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            sea.setImage(cursor.getBlob(2));
            sea.setComment(cursor.getString(3));

            dbsearch.add(sea);
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return dbsearch;
    }
```

and this is my activity :

```
private void search(String name) {

    persons = (ArrayList<DBSearch>) databaseAdapter.searchByName(name);
    SearchAdapter personListAdapter = new SearchAdapter(persons, this);
    personListView.setAdapter(personListAdapter);
    personListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),AWDetailsActivity.class);

                    String my_id = persons.get(position).getId("id").toString();
                    i.putExtra("id", my_id);

                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Out put of `String my_id` ??

Comment: hi my _id  for save position